# In what position to play Monti's Chardash solo (Sautille arpegios with melisms) violin bars 34-40

Tags: technique, violin, fingering

Who knows in what position to play [Monti's Czardas solo](https://imslp.org/wiki/Special:ReverseLookup/103621) (Sautille arpegios with melisms) violin bars 34-40 and to use open E string or play E on a A string instead? Is there any violin tabulature for that?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure we are talking about the same passage, but if we are, the first two bars of the first half map reasonably well to first position, and the first two bars of the second half to third position.  The second beat of the third bar of each half is where it gets tricky: I tend to move to third position there in the first half of the passage, and to second(!) in the second half of it.

With regard to using open E string: you use it when the rest of the group is on the E string as well, and you don't use it when the rest of the group is not on the E string as well.

Answer (score 0):

@player777 the section you talk about starts from bar 38 and not 34.

The first arpegio I play in 1st position. I use to play open E.

The 2nd arpegio I often play also in 1st position (with open A and open E), but it is actually difficult in the 1st position because of the string crossings which makes the sautille stroke difficult. I have also practiced it in the 2nd position, streching the fourth finger up to g on the A string but keeping the hand in 2nd position. This is better for the sautille stroke. The strech up to g with the fourth finger isn't that hard because the second finger is high on the D string (on g sharp) and the first finger is high on the A string (on c sharp). 
I have also tried it out in 3rd position but I don't really like that solution.

Note an interesting thing: If you play the first arpegio with fourth finger instead of open E and then play the 2nd arpegio in third position then both arpegios will have the exact same finger pattern. I find that solution quite difficult because of the change of the position of fourth finger on the two strings high-low-high fourth finger when you go back and fourth. But, as I said, at least you get the same finger pattern. The strech of the fourth finger in the 2nd position as I said above I like better. But if you can manage a good sautille with awkward string crossings then the 1st position is the easiest way of getting good resonance I would say.

Well, in any case the 2nd arpegio is simply more difficult than the 1st one no matter which option you choose.

EDIT: Elaboration. In the scale at the end of the 2nd arpegio I usually go up in the 3rd position to end with 3rd finger on F. I often do that no matter in which position I played the arpegio just before. Well, if I am in the 2nd position in the arpegio then I go down to the 1st position on the open A after G sharp in the 3rd bar of that section and then up in the 3rd position with 2nd finger on the note E although it can also happen that I go to the 3rd position on the F only.

EDIT 2: You mentioned "violin tabulature". What would that look like for this kind of topic?